# SwiftUI: Text Field getting cut off

Tags: swiftui

The textField on my SwiftUI app is getting cut off. But it doesn't happen every time. It seems to happen at random.

[image: Screenshot of app showing text getting cut off]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      // Target row
      HStack {
        Text("Put the bullseye as close as you can to:")
        Text("\(target)")
      }
      Spacer()
      // Slider row
      HStack {
        Text("1")
        Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...100) {_ in
          print(self.sliderValue)
        }
        Text("100")
      }
      Spacer()
      // Hit me button row
      Button(action: {
        print("Button pressed")
        self.alertIsVisible = true
      }) {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hit Me!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)

      }
      .alert(isPresented: $alertIsVisible) { () -> Alert in
        let roundedValue = Int(sliderValue.rounded())
        let score = pointsForCurrentRound()
        return Alert(title: Text("Hello there!"), message: Text("The slider's value is \(roundedValue)!\n" +
          "You scored \(score) points this round"
          ), dismissButton: .default(Text("Awesome")))
      }
      Spacer()
      // Score and start over button row
      HStack {
        Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
          Text("Start Over")
        }
        Spacer()
        Text("Score:")
        Text("999999")
        Spacer()
        Text("Round:")
        Text("999")
        Spacer()
        Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
          Text("Info")
        }
      }
      .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
  }
```

I've tried adding padding trailing the text field and before the target. I've tried adding padding to the leading edge of the target. I've tried giving using the frame method on the text field to add a min length. None of these work.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? I am using Xcode 11.1 official, and have worked on the same project, and it is fixed in iOS 13.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using Xcode version 11.2, the most recent release. What is fixed in iOS 13.1 and above?

Comment: Ah, so in iOS 13.1 and above, the Text takes the whole space according to the its size instead of truncating. Can you tell me when does it happen randomly, in previews or simulator/real device?

Comment: It happens in both preview and the simulator. I haven't tried it on a real device.

Comment: I just reinstalled 11.1 and tried the app. The text no longer cuts off. So must be something in 11.2. I'll file a bug report.  Thank you for helping me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across this exact situation! After a few moments of searching, trial, and errors, I finally figured it out. The text view is trying to resize and one of the parent views have animations enabled. If anyone having this same issue adds .animation(nil) to the Text, this will likely solve the issue.

```
VStack {
    Text("\(Int(self.viewModel.ProgressPercentage * 100.0))%")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .animation(nil)
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 21):

You may add fixedSize() to lock the labels.

```
HStack {
  Text("Put the bullseye as close as you can to:").fixedSize()
  Text("\(target)").fixedSize()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
Text("hello!")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

Text could expand horizontally, not vertically